# Using google maps javascript api in an ios application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Using apache Cordova to create a web based application that uses Google maps should normally download the google maps api to use it. The [Apple store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) state this :

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

How should we access the google maps api then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That clause is to prevent  applications that get through the approval process, disguised as something in the begining and later change their fundamental function.

An extreme example would be an application downloading new, malicious executable code after it has been installed on the user's device.

They have used the words in broad sence so that they can reject any app that in any way tries to be harmful to the user. It would be impossible to specifically describe every technique and specific way this could happen, so Apple keeps the wording loose.

Apps download code all the time, consider an application that accesses an API that returns JSON formatted responses, this falls under category of downloading code, but such apps are never rejected

You don't have to worry about using google API, unless you plan on misusing the API to do something harmful

Just for your reassurance, I posted a link for an app that uses google API https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/gargash-insurance/id836602923?mt=8  , it is not rejected from the store